# How does Stripe 3D secure works in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, stripe-payments

How to implement stripe 3D Secure on ionic? i am checking the document https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/web and https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/web-manual but there is no clear approch for this. Have anyone implemented Stripe 3d-secure on ionic?

Comment: Hi @Dilan have you solved this? Could you please kindly help me ? I'm having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think this plugin might be useful for you here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/stripe